# WPF touch input temporarily not working after modal dialog was closed (maybe only Windows 11 issue ?)

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, windows-11

I did not find any suitable solution for my problem.
I have a WPF application and I created a custom textbox control that opens a modal dialog which acts as virtual numpad.
So right now it works as intended: I touch into the textbox control, die virtual numpad is displayed, I can change the value, press the Enter button, the numpad is closed and the new value is shown in the textbox control.
However, after I do that my WPF page that contains the textbox control does not react to any touch input. The strange thing is, I can count the touch input and after 20 touches it does react again as normal. So I was guessing that this might have to do with multitouch or something?
I already made sure that the TouchEventArgs Handled property is set to true and I also applied that fix for the ShowDialog() call to be put into Dispatcher.Invoke() call.
I'm running my application on Windows 11, maybe it is a new problem. On Windows 10 I did not experience such issues (right now I can test my application on Windows 10 only with the Windows Simulator as my only touch device runs Windows 11).

Did you experience someting similar or do you have any suggestions what to do or what to check?

Before you ask why I'm not using the regular windows touch keyboard: I need a touch keyboard that shows the value that is edited (like the calculator).

Update: This seems to be the same issue as described here in the answer by Andy: [WPF touch application freezes (partially)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049673/wpf-touch-application-partially-freezes-on-net-framework-4-7)
Somehow the touch input is only recognized as mouse click. I can see it, because the mouse cursor changes. When touch is active on each touch a little circle is displayed and during the loss of touch I only see the point of the click or sometimes a text cursor. But after 10 touches or so it works normally again.